# I want to get an output like this in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python to interact with mysql and when I access columns from mysql i get an output like this:
[('some', 't5vd._kZ'), ('something', 'anything')]

i want it to be:
some, t5vd._kZ
something, anything

my code:

```
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = '####',
    password = '######',
    database = 'database'
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM passwords')
result = str(cursor.fetchall())
passwd = ''
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
for tup in result:
    print(*tup)
```